# Micrososft version of email sign-in on external websites

Tags: authorization, hotmail

Google, Facebook, twitter all of them have pretty well known and documented "APIs" to allow web designers to include "social sign-in" in their websites (like stack overflow does in the login options).

I'd like to know if Microsoft supplies any options to do the same but for Hotmail/live/windows accounts? And if so where can I find documentation on how to include Micrososft account signin on a website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  It's called a "Microsoft account", and previously, was called "Microsoft Wallet", "Microsoft Passport", and "Windows Live ID".

For details, see the wiki page at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_account